# "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages." when trying to install dnsutils?

Tags: apt

I'm trying to install `dnsutils` but I am getting this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dnsutils

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dnsutils : Depends: libbind9-80 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.8) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4.2ubuntu3.4 is to be installed
            Depends: libdns81 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.8) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4.2ubuntu3.4 is to be installed
            Depends: libisc83 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.8) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4.2ubuntu3.4 is to be installed
            Depends: libisccfg82 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.8) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4.2ubuntu3.4 is to be installed
            Depends: liblwres80 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.8) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4.2ubuntu3.4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've seen some people post about this particular error, but I'm not finding any solid answers.  Any idea why I'm getting this or how to fix it?

I have tried `apt-get` update and `apt-get upgrade` as well as `clean` and `autoclean`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install missing dependencies first, open Synaptic Package Manager from launcher and search for the lib files (libbind9-80,libdns81,libisc83 etc..) you are missing. Install all of them, then try to install dnsutils again via sudo.